# Converting from bytestring to uuid str?

Tags: java, arrays, string, byte, uuid

To convert a string to a byte string let's say we do something like this:

```
public static byte[] uuidStrToBytes(@Nonnull String uuidStr) {
    UUID uuid = UUID.fromString(uuidStr.trim());
    return toByteArray(uuid);
}

public static ByteString uuidStrToByteString(@Nonnull String uuidStr) {
    return ByteString.copyFrom(uuidStrToBytes(uuidStr));
}
```

How would we reverse this though, ie what if we want to convert a Bytestring to uuid?

Comment: What is `ByteString`? Not found in standard Java.

Comment: Your question already shows how to convert from String to ByteString? Did you mean the other way around? If so then did you try `byteString.toString()` from the [API](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/ByteString.html#toString--)? Then just parse it to back to a UUID: `UUID.fromString(yourString);`

Comment: @sorifiend oops meant the otherway around, thank you!